# Python Pandas, apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use apply to avoid an `iterrows()` iterator in a function:

However that pandas method is poorly documented and I can't find example on how to use it, except for the lame `.apply(sq.rt)` in the documentation... No example on how to use arguments etc...

Anyway, here a toy example on what I try to do.

In my understanding `apply` will actually do the same as `iterrows()`, ie, iterate (over the rows if axis=0). On each iteration the input `x` of the function should be the row iterated over. However the error messages I keep receiving sort of disprove that assumption...

```
grid = np.random.rand(5,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(grid)

def multiply(x):
    x[3]=x[0]*x[1]

df = df.apply(multiply, axis=0)
```

The example above returns an empty df. Can anyone shed some light on my misunderstanding?

Comment: The method's documentation page is not that rich but you can take a look at [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#function-application).

Comment: @ayhan This is actually what solved my problem. thx

Answer (score 10):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

grid = np.random.rand(5,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(grid)

def multiply(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]

df['multiply'] = df.apply(multiply, axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Results in:

```
          0         1  multiply
0  0.550750  0.713054  0.392715
1  0.061949  0.661614  0.040987
2  0.472134  0.783479  0.369907
3  0.827371  0.277591  0.229670
4  0.961102  0.137510  0.132162
```

---

Explanation:

The function you are `apply`ing, needs to return a value. You are also applying this to each row, not column. The [`axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) parameter you passed was incorrect in this regard.

Finally, notice that I am setting this equal to the `'multiply'` column outside of my function. You can easily change this to be `df[3] = ...` like you have and get a dataframe like this:

```
          0         1         3
0  0.550750  0.713054  0.392715
1  0.061949  0.661614  0.040987
2  0.472134  0.783479  0.369907
3  0.827371  0.277591  0.229670
4  0.961102  0.137510  0.132162
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that you can use lambda functions as well. See their documentation [Apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html?highlight=lambda#apply)

For your example, you can run:

```
df['multiply'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[0] * row[1], axis = 1)
```

which produces the same output as @Andy

This can be useful if your function is in the form of

```
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b

df['multiply'] = df.apply(lambda row: multiply(row[0] ,row[1]), axis = 1)
```

More examples in the section [Enhancing Performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)

Answer (score 3):

One of the rules of Pandas Zen says: `always try to find a vectorized solution first`.

`.apply(..., axis=1)` is not vectorized!

Consider alternatives:

```
In [164]: df.prod(axis=1)
Out[164]:
0    0.770675
1    0.539782
2    0.318027
3    0.597172
4    0.211643
dtype: float64

In [165]: df[0] * df[1]
Out[165]:
0    0.770675
1    0.539782
2    0.318027
3    0.597172
4    0.211643
dtype: float64
```

Timing against 50.000 rows DF:

```
In [166]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [167]: df.shape
Out[167]: (50000, 2)

In [168]: %timeit df.apply(multiply, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.12 s per loop

In [169]: %timeit df.prod(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.23 ms per loop

In [170]: def multiply_vect(x1, x2):
     ...:     return x1*x2
     ...:

In [171]: %timeit multiply_vect(df[0], df[1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 604 µs per loop
```

**Conclusion:** use `.apply()` as a very last resort (i.e. when nothing else helps)

Comment: U Hi thx  - yeah i know... I was trying to find a simple example to ask about my problem but I think I sort of failed... thi sexample is too simple and doesnt mention 2 pb that I was experiencing, 1 is how to retrieve the index of the row being iterated on ( I believe it is turned into the Name attribute if the row, the other being how to pass a dataframe as an argument... anyway thx.. I ll think about it again, maybe I 'll ask directly with the function that I am trying to do, which is a percentile function

Comment: I think OP's purpose in using `multiply` is as a toy example for understanding how to use `.apply()`, as is the title of the thread.

Comment: @jimbasquiat, yes, it's better ask a new question, describing your particular problem. Most probably there is another (better) solution, compared to `.apply(..., axis=1)`

Comment: @MaxU reposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482830/python-pandas-apply-function-and-percentile-calculation

Answer (score 1):

When [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)-ing a function, you need that function to return the result for that operation over the column/row. You are getting `None` because `multiply` doesn't return, evidently. That is, `apply` should be returning a result between particular values, not doing the assignment itself.

You're also iterating over the wrong axis, here. Your current code takes the first and second element of each *column* and multiplies them together.

A correct `multiply` function:

```
def multiply(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]

df[3] = df.apply(multiply, 'columns')
```

**With that being said**, you can do much better than `apply` here, as it is not a vectorized operation. Just multiply the columns together directly.

```
df[3] = df[0]*df[1]
```

In general, you should avoid `apply` when possible as it is not much more than a loop itself under the hood.