# Python, Pandas apply function and percentile calculation

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a function that compute a percentile column based on 2 other columns in the dataframe: 
for each row, the function recreate a mini df with only the last 20 rows, compute the absolute difference for each of them, and then assign a percentile to the current row.

I was suggested by a respondent to a previous question to repost that more specific question regarding apply

```
grid = np.random.rand(40,2)
full = pd.DataFrame(grid, columns=['value'])

def percentile(x, df):
    if int(x.name)<20:
        pass
    else:
        df_temp = df.loc[(int(x.name)-20):int(x.name),'value']
        bucketted = [b for b  in df_temp.value if b < df_temp.loc[int(x.name), 'value']]
        return len(bucketted)/0.2        

full['percentile'] = full.apply(percentile, axis=1, args=(full,))
```

for intellectual curiosity - since this works - if anyone has a neater /faster way to approach the problem.

Comment: Could you make a smaller (5-7 rows) sample data set and show the desired data set, because currently it's bit hard to understand the function logic?

Comment: @MaxU yeah that's what I though in the first place. Now I remove a bit of the complexity, and thats really the bare bone logic for percentile computation: http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-percentiles-in-statistics/

Comment: the code is broken now - could you check it?

Comment: you may also want to check [window.Rolling.quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.quantile.html)